# Is there a list of Force powers?

Tags: star-wars, online-resources

Does anybody know a website where I can find a comprehensive list of every power or application of the Force ever used in Star Wars by movie, TV episode, novel, comic, game, sourcebook, and other sources?

Sorry, but besides Wookieepedia. I've already been there.

Comment: Isn't this a list question?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - ah. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: How is this not "virtually unlimited"? New comics, games, books and episodes are in production. New powers or applications are introduced constantly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have fundamental problems with anything that lists "Force Powers". Obi-Wan Kenobi describes the Force as

> "what gives a Jedi his power. It's an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us; it binds the galaxy together."

As another example, in *Legacy of the Force: Betrayal*, in the final scene, Jacen Solo is talking to Nelani Dinn.

> "Stop listening with just your ears," Jacen said. "Look into the Force. Do you really see any flow from [Lumiya] to me, from me to her..."  <sub>hardback edition, page 373</sub>

These two examples both lend credence to the idea that the Force **isn't a list of spells**, but rather a discipline of art, where energy is manipulated. The "powers" you seek were created by video games to make things easy.

Now, we can acknowledge the "list of spells approach" with caution, because any Force-user will be stronger in one aspect of the art than in another, and his skills may pale in comparision to somebody else's. We know that Corran Horn, as well as the entire Halcyon family tree, consistently struggled with telekinesis, but that failure at the seemingly simplest task did not hold him back from becoming a Jedi Master. He evidently excelled in other areas.

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I don't think you can approach the Force the way you have thus far.

Answer (score 7):

**One of the most comprehensive and extensive [Force Powers lists](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_power) online can be found at Wookieepedia.**

I will also suggest you take anything you see there with a grain of salt since so much of the information there is in dispute as to whether it is canon or not. Many of the sources are from a variety of gaming sources, RPGs, video games and books from various authors.

**EDIT:**

No. There isn't anyplace that has gathered every resource Wookieepedia has used and bothered to compile them. There are plenty of sites that list discrete elements depending on what games they're supporting.

You always have the option of using Wookieepedia's resource list and creating the powers in your own comprehensive list. They are nice enough to list their sources for reference.

Answer (score -1):

As usual, the best resources for stuff like this can be found in a [GURPS resource](http://members.upc.nl/l.deckers3/pdf/GURPS%203rd%20Star%20Wars%20-%20Space%20Worldbook.pdf). Here is an unofficial work book for Star Wars that has a pretty good list of the force powers one can find in the movies and books.

Comment: Why the -1? Is there a list of force powers? Yes, and here it is.